# Android: Odd behaviour when screen is turned off?

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a game and use a WakeLock to keep the screen from going to sleep while the user is playing. However, I'm encountering some weird behavior when the screen is manually put to sleep..

My current approach is to store away the game info in OnPause() and load them back up when OnCreate() is called. This works fine if I hit the home button and start my app back up. However, turning the screen off seems to call OnPause() a couple times..in addition to some other funky behavior. Can anyone offer an explanation of why turning the screen off is different than hitting home?

According to Logcat, here's the sequence of events.

When Screen is turned off-OnPause is called; OnCreate is called; OnResume is called; OnPause is called again

When screen is turned back on- OnResume is called (before phone is even unlocked)